# flask, python error : jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'flask.ctx._AppCtxGlobals object' has no attribute 'lock'

Tags: python, flask

I'm getting an error and I can't understand what it is, I have no knowledge of python.

jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'flask.ctx._AppCtxGlobals object' has no attribute 'lock'

[screenshot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6b7b.png)

```
    @app.route('/login', methods = ['GET', 'POST']) 
def login():
if g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect(url_for('logout'))
form = LoginForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    user = User.query.filter_by(name=form.user.data, password=form.password.data).first()
    if user is not None:
        login_user(user) 
        identity_changed.send(current_app._get_current_object(),
            identity=Identity(user.id))
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else:
form.errors["loginerror"] = "Login fehlgeschlagen"
        return render_template('login.html', form=form)
return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

I couldn't even understand where the error came from